# Fortran round-off error with floating point operations

Tags: computational-geometry, fortran, floating-point

I have simple code, which flags nodes with in region enclosed by cylinder. On implementing the code, the result is mild tilt of the cylinder observed case with $\theta=90^{\circ}$.

The algorithm for checking any point inside arbitrarily oriented cylinder is as follows. Let $\vec{r}$ be the vector joining center $\vec{c}$ and arbitrary point $\vec{o}$, and $$\vec{r}=\vec{c}-\vec{o}.$$ For orientation vector $\vec{o}$, the projection of $\vec{r}$ on it is,
$$ u = \vec{r}\cdot\vec{o}.$$
Therefore, the perpendicular vector is,
$$\vec{p}=\vec{r}-u\cdot\vec{o}.$$
For a cylinder of length $2l$ and radius $a$, check
$$\vec{p}.\vec{p}<a^2  \hspace{1cm} \text{for } -l\leq u \leq l. $$

**The actual issue:**
The above algorithm is implemented in Fortran. The code checks for points in Cartesian grid if inside the cylinder. Following being the test case:
The cylinder makes an angle $\theta=90^{\circ}$ in the yz-plane with respect to y-axis. Therefore, the orientation vector $\vec{o}$ is (0, 1, 0).

**Case 1:**
Orientation vector is assigned directly with $\vec{o}=(0.0,1.0,0.0)$. This results in perfect cylinder with $\theta=90^{\circ}.$
[image]

**Case 2:**
Orientation vector is specified with intrinsic Fortran functions with double precision accuracy `dsin` and `dcos` with $\vec{o}=(0.0, \sin(\pi/2.0), \cos(\pi/2.0))$ with $\pi$ value assigned with more than 20 significant decimal points. The resulting cylinder results in mild tilt.

[image]
The highlighted region indicates the extra material due to tilt of cylinder with respect to Cartesian axes. I also tried [architecture specific maximum precision "pi" value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157920/why-define-pi-4atan1) This also results in same problem.

This shows like the actual angle made by cylinder is not $90^\circ$. Can anyone suggest valid solution for this problem. I need to use the inbuilt trigonometric functions for arbitrary angles and looking for accurate cell flagging method.

Note: All operations are performed with double precision accuracy.

Comment: Though not related to the question, could you tell me how you made that nice picture? (Now I'm looking for the way to make such a picture for my study...)

Comment: `Paraview` and use color palette as "print"

Comment: Could you be a little more precise about what you are drawing exactly? It would be much easier to help if there is a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is $a$ an integer? Why does the cylinder look like a union of small cubes? What are the "nodes"? Are you doing something like testing whether points with *integer* coordinates belong to the cylinder? It could just be that your comparisons fall right on the boundary of the cylinder, which is ill-conditioned.

Comment: Those looking for the code for this could start at the cross-posted version -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897677/fortran-round-off-errors.

Answer (score 2):

It would be really nice to look at the code, compiler you are using and compiler options. However, I can suggest couple of things to test right away:

1. Instead of specifying 0.0 and 2.0 as in your text, use 0.0_dp and 2.0_dp, whenever you use any constants. That will make sure that double precision will be used for them. (dp=kind(0.0d0)) Moreover, I would say that multiplication by 0.5_dp is preferred to division by 2.0_dp.
   Say,

   ```
   tmp_sin=dsin(pid*0.5_dp)
   tmp_cos=dcos(pid*0.5_dp)
   o=/0.0_dp,tmp_sin,tmp_cos/
   ```
2. Another thing to try, would be to create a double-precision variable pid_over_two that will have a value of pi/2 with >20 significant digits and try your code (with your compiler settings) on that.
3. Make sure that you **do not** compile this code with -no-prec-div option that allows for non-IEEE standard division.
4. Make sure that when you output the data for visualisation, you are using the correct format specifiers

These are the basic advices I can suggest without looking inside of the code.
Also, it would be valuable to see, what output does your code (under your compiler/platform/settings) produce for:

```
dsin(pid/2.0)
dsin(pid/2.0_dp)
dsin(0.5_dp*pid)
dcos(pid/2.0)
dcos(pid/2.0_dp)
dcos(0.5_dp*pid)
```